# How to Create an Azure policy where a user with owner access cannot remove other users with owner access

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am looking for creating custom Azure policy where a user with owner access cannot remove other users with owner access.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving owner role, you can use Contributor roles which cannot change Rbac assignments. Otherwise, you can use management group if you want someone has higher level access and higher scope.